# Hql Query.nor working

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, hql

I need to write the query according to this logic
`LeadRepository.getQualifiedLeadsWithoutClosedWonOrLost` to the following query:

```
select l.id from prospectr360.lead l, prospectr360.lead_action la where l.id = la.lead_id and la.action_id = 6 and l.id not in (select l.id from prospectr360.lead_action la, prospectr360.action a, prospectr360.lead l where la.action_id = a.id and la.lead_id = l.id and reason_id in (61,65))
```

and I have written

```
@Query("SELECT lead.id " +
       "  FROM Lead lead, " +
       "       LeadAction la, " +
       "  WHERE lead.id = leadAction.lead.id"+
       "  AND leadAction.action.id = 6" +
       "  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 " +
       "                     FROM Lead lead, " +
       "                          Action action, " +
       "                    WHERE action.id = la.action.id" +
       "                      AND la.lead.id = lead.id" +
       "                      AND la.reason.id in (61,65)" +
       ")")
List<Lead> getQualifiedLeadsWithoutClosedWonOrLost();
}
```

Comment: Hi Sam, your question is about to get closed. Could you please provide additional info like what error messages are you getting. Another thing is portion of code that you have pasted is incomplete. Thanks.

Comment: Provide the error log and what is the problem, or are you just expecting users will help you translate your SQL query to HQL? Downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it

```
@Query("SELECT lead " +
        "  FROM Lead lead, " +
        "       LeadAction leadAction " +
        "  WHERE lead.id = leadAction.lead.id"+
        "  AND leadAction.action.id = 6" +
        "  AND lead.id NOT IN (SELECT lead1.id " +
        "                     FROM Lead lead1, " +
        "                          LeadAction la ," +
        "                          Action action " +
        "                    WHERE la.action.id = action.id" +
        "                      AND la.lead.id = lead1.id" +
        "                      AND la.reason.id in (61,65)" +
                   ")")
List<Lead> getQualifiedLeadsWithoutClosedWonOrLost();
```